# invoking smart contract through geth console

Tags: go-ethereum

i am trying in invoke the smart contract through geth i am successful in doing it but the problem is i have a function in the contract which should give me the list of candidates. i getting it but the last item is not getting displayed properly(it is not behaving the way i want ) the code and the output of it is below

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.4 .25;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract Election {
  //owner of the contract
  address public owner;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    addCandidate("NOTA");
    addCandidate("BJP");
    addCandidate("CONGRESS");
    addCandidate("JDS");
    addCandidate("others");
    addCandidate("jdu");
    addCandidate("amma-party");

  }

  //storing the valid users added by owner(admin)
  address[] validVoters;

  //store accounts(voters) that have already voted
  mapping(address => bool) voters;

  //logging the actiion performed on voter validation
  event LogAccess(address indexed by, string method, string desc);

  //Candidate structure
  struct Candidate {
    int id;
    string name;
    int voteCount;
    address[] votersList;
  }

  //store names into the array
  string[] candidateNames;

  //store id's into array
  int[] candidateIds;

  //store the Candidates(for final result)

  mapping(int => Candidate) public candidates;

  //store the Candidates id
  int candidateId = 100;

  //adding candidates into list
  function addCandidate(string name) private {
    candidateId++;
    address[] memory votedPeople;
    candidates[candidateId] = Candidate(candidateId, name, 0, votedPeople);
    candidateIds.push(candidateId);
    candidateNames.push(name);

  }

  //to get the list of Candidate id's'
  function getCandidateIds() public view returns(int[]) {
    return candidateIds;
  }

  //to get the list of candidates names
  function getCandidateNames() public view returns(string[]) {
    return candidateNames;
  }

  //adding the valid voters into the array(only owner(admin) of contract can)
  function addVoters(address voter) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    validVoters.push(voter);
  }

  //to delete a voter from the list if required only admin is allowed
  function deleteVoter(address voter) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    for (uint i = 0; i < validVoters.length; i++) {
      if (validVoters[i] == voter) {
        delete validVoters[i];
      }
    }
  }

  //validating the voters 
  function isValidVoter(address voter, string method) private returns(bool) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < validVoters.length; i++) {
      if (validVoters[i] == voter) {
        emit LogAccess(voter, method, "successful access(eligible to vote)");
        return true;
      }

    }
    emit LogAccess(voter, method, "access failed(not eligible to vote)");
    return false;
  }

  //voting function
  function vote(int _candidateId) public {
    if (isValidVoter(msg.sender, "vote")) {
      //require to check user as not voted
      require(!voters[msg.sender]);

      //check for valid Candidate
      require(_candidateId > 0 && _candidateId <= candidateId);

      //record the vote 
      voters[msg.sender] = true;

      // update candidate vote Count
      candidates[_candidateId].voteCount++;

      //add voter address to the cadidate
      candidates[_candidateId].votersList.push(msg.sender);

    }

  }

  function getVotersList(int id) public view returns(address[]) {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    return candidates[id].votersList;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What output are you expecting? We don't know your input.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a big contract, it is not easy to find an error.

I see, that first item in your response is empty, but last item doesn't exist in response, that is why I can assume that code written with error, increment of `candidateId` should be after push:

```
function addCandidate(string name) private
{
    address[] memory votedPeople;
    candidates[candidateId] = Candidate(candidateId,name,0,votedPeople);
    candidateIds.push(candidateId);
    candidateNames.push(name);
    candidateId++;
 }
```